# Workbox v5 unable to ensure service worker stays alive when updating cache for various routes

Tags: vue.js, webpack, service-worker, workbox

We're currently using Workbox (v5) for a fairly large SaaS platform. Most of the routes are setup to use `NetworkFirst`.

Something I've not been able to work out is why, for some routes, when running the platform in none-production mode there are a few Workbox warnings saying **Unable to ensure service worker stays alive when updating cache for [route]**.

Does anyone know what the message actually means, i.e. why is it being triggered? I see that it's coming from the **ExpirationPlugin**.

The frontend of the platform is **Vue.js** with **Webpack**, and we're using the `WorkboxWebpackPlugin` with `InjectManifest`.

It's been configured as per below:

```
config.plugin('workbox')
  .use(WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest, [{
    swSrc: './src/sw.js',
    swDest: 'sw.js',
    maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5242880, // 5MB
    exclude: [
      /\web.config$/,
      /refresh.html$/,
      /sw.js$/
    ]
  }])
```

Fingers-crossed I'll be able to learn more on this warning message. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing further testing, it looks like this warning is displayed when a route that uses `NetworkFirst` with `networkTimeoutSeconds` and the response from the route exceeds the number of seconds set in `networkTimeoutSeconds`.